# Attempting to learn SendMail Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i'm new to the script side of sheets and i'm not 100% sure on what i'm doing and just trying to learn a bit more.

I have this script :

```
function DebtorMailSend(g) {
 If (g.rangecolumnstart != 7 || g.Value != 60) return;
Const rData = g.source.getactivesheet().getrange(g.range.rowStart,1,1,5).getValues()
let c = rData[0][0]
let i = rData[0][1]
let e = rData[0][2]
let b = rData[0][3]
let n = rData[0][4]

let msg = "Hi,"  "I hope you're well." "We have been reviewing our records and understand that invoice number" + n + "relating to UK services have not yet been settled." "We would be grateful if you could expedite payment and let us know when we can expect to receive the remittance." "Should you have any queries or require further details, please do not hesitate to contact me." "Kind Regards," "Ken"
GmailApp.sendEmail(e,c + "- Invoice Reminder - " + n,msg)
}
```

And i cant save because of an issue with the Return, which i don't fully understand.

> Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected string line: 10 file: Code.gs

I have a bunch of stuff i need to add like a 2nd condition and CC's but i'm trying to get the basics first.

Of course i'm not expecting anyone to solve the whole thing, but any explanations or guidance is very much appreciated, feel free to add a tab with guidance or tips!

---

Here is the screenshot of the sheet:

[image]

Comment: For starters, try to convert the `If` and `Const` into lower case `if` and `const`. As for the rest, the code looks more or less fine. But it depends on how the function is called.

Comment: Always quote the exact error. Pay attention to the wording of the error.

Comment: [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure. Questions asked here should be self contained. If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet. [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: @YuriKhristich Thanks for that i'll make those lower case and remember for the future, will it always be lower case for script commands?

Comment: @TheMaster Sorry the error after the capitalisation error is now "Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected string line: 10 file: Code.gs" as for the email issue i appreciate the heads up, i'm not majorly concerned as they're not important email addresses

Comment: Error in the line 10, well, there are wrong used quote marks `"` as well. You have to change the `"Hi,"  "I hope you're well." "We have be...` to `"Hi,\nI hope you're well.\nWe have be...` etc. The `\n` works like 'Enter' key.

Comment: And if you mean automatically send emails as soon as some value in some cell(s) meets some condition there can be problem if the value is changing automatically. Automatic changes can't run a script. At some point there should be manual changes: typing in a cell, click on a button, click on a menu, etc. Or it could be time driven trigger script that will check the changes every day or every hour. Or it could be trigger that fires after a user fill out and send a form. It would be easier if you describe your ultimate goal.

Comment: Even if you're not concerned with the email address, question should be self contained. Use image/table first.

Comment: @YuriKhristich Ooo didn't know about \n that will help allot with formatting how i want it to come out, as for script not going by automatic changes like the date column, i'm assuming it would be fine to just add a column with a drop down with "Send" as an option and using that as a trigger?

Comment: The ultimate goal is to have an email send based on 2 conditions, 1 being client or internal and the other being 60 days or as it would be now "send" in a different column, i'll hopefully have 2 scripts so that it can send different emails depending on if it is client or internal, and it will create the subject. body and CC the correct email

Comment: *column with a drop down with "Send"* — it doesn't look like an efficient way to sent many emails (if I understand the workflow correctly). You will need to select the 'Send' option in each row every time you want to send the email. Probably it makes sense to create one button (or custom menu) 'Send all emails'. Script will check all the rows on the sheet and send all the emails at once (whenever cells of the row meet some conditions).

Comment: And beware, this way you can send not more than 100 emails per day: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Comment: If you want the 'semi-automatic' mode it could be a script that will check all the rows and set checkboxes in a column in the rows that meet conditions. Then you can click on the checkboxes and it will send emails, one click = one email.

Comment: So on the main sheet it wouldn't be a very high volume i would estimate that at any 1 time only 5-6 should reach 60 days at once, with my limited knowledge at the moment with scripts it would probably be better for me to just have that send column as the less moving parts i need to figure out the better haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused when you define the `msg` variable.

When defining a variable, you can't assign it with a value with more than 1 string unless you concatenate them.

**Try this instead:**

```
//On Edit Trigger
function DebtorMailSend(e) {
  let editedCellValue = e.value;
  let editedRow = e.range.getRow();
  let editedColumn = e.range.getColumn();
  if (editedColumn != 6 || editedCellValue != 60) return;
  const rData = e.source
    .getActivesheet()
    .getRange(editedRow, 1, 1, 5)
    .getValues();
  let [column1, column2, column3, column4, column5] = rData[0];
  let msg = `Hi,\nI hope you're well.\nWe have been reviewing our records and understand that invoice number ${column5} relating to UK services have not yet been settled.\nWe would be grateful if you could expedite payment and let us know when we can expect to receive the remittance.\nShould you have any queries or require further details, please do not hesitate to contact me.\nKind Regards,\nKen`;
  GmailApp.sendEmail(column3, `${column1}- Invoice Reminder - ${column5}`, msg, { cc: "example@gmail.com" });
}
```

**What I've changed:**

1. Updated the msg string to concatenate the strings. Also added `\n` to create new lines where the string were previously separated.
2. Simplified assigning the [c, i, e, b, n] variables using [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
3. Updated the concatenation to [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead of using + to join the strings.
4. Lower cased the If function and the Const variable.
5. Fixed a few bugs with how the edited values were being pulled.
6. Fixed an issue where the column if statement was looking at column G instead of F. Columns start at position 0. So 0 is actually column A.
7. Renamed a few variables for clarity
8. Renamed the parameter g to e to follow onEdit best practices.
9. Adjusted the capitalization in a few areas.
10. Added the option to define the cc emails using an [object parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options) (separate emails by commas). Just replace `example@gmail.com` with the email address that should be cc'd.

**Notes:**

- If you'd like to add more formatting to your message, [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp) might help.
- Javascript is very sensitive to the capitalization of the code. Ensure you're following the capitalization exactly as they are in the documentation.
- If you're looking to get more control over the formatting of the email, you could use the [htmlBody](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options) object parameter option to use html instead of a formatted string.

**Edit:**
Based on the information that Column F is a formula that isn't manually edited, I've adjusted my answer to be a dropdown menu trigger.

How to run:

1. Run the onOpen script from within the code editor
2. Refresh the Google Sheet doc
3. You'll notice a new menu appear in your spreadsheet called "Send Late Payment Emails"
4. Whenever you're ready to send the reminder emails, use the "Send Emails" dropdown option from the "Send Late Payment Emails" menu and it'll send an email for each late invoice that doesn't have "Sent" in column F
5. One the email is sent, the script will automatically update column F to "Sent".

[image]

```
/**
 * Creates a new dropdown menu on the top of your sheet that can trigger the DebtorMailSend script
 */
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu("Send Late Payment Emails")
    .addItem("Send Emails", "DebtorMailSend")
    .addToUi();
}

function DebtorMailSend() {
  let activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  let dataRange = activeSheet.getRange(2, 1, activeSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 7) //only looks at columns A -> G
  let sheetValues = dataRange.getValues()

  //Loops through each row of the spreadsheet
  for (var [rowIndex, rowValues] of sheetValues.entries()) {
    var [client, invoiceWith, contact, billingManager, invoiceNumber, status, daysOutstanding] = rowValues
    
    //Checks if the invoice is outstanding and avoids sending an email twice
    if (daysOutstanding < 60 || status == "Sent") continue;

    //Sends email
    var msg = `Hi,\nI hope you're well.\nWe have been reviewing our records and understand that invoice number ${invoiceNumber} relating to UK services have not yet been settled.\nWe would be grateful if you could expedite payment and let us know when we can expect to receive the remittance.\nShould you have any queries or require further details, please do not hesitate to contact me.\nKind Regards,\nKen`;
    GmailApp.sendEmail(columnC, `${client}- Invoice Reminder - ${invoiceNumber}`, msg, {cc: "example@gmail.com"});
    
    //Updates the status to "Sent" after an email has been sent
    activeSheet.getRange(rowIndex + 2, 6).setValue("Sent")
  }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246180/discussion-on-answer-by-jeanjai77-attempting-to-learn-sendmail-script).

Answer (score 0):

As an example it could be two functions like this:

```
// set checkboxes in 13th column for the rows that have >60 in 6th column

function set_checkboxes() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var days_column = 6;
  var checkboxes_column = 13;

  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();

  data.forEach((row,i) => { if (row[days_column-1] > 60) 
      sh.getRange(i+1,checkboxes_column).insertCheckboxes().check();
  });
}


// send emails for every row that has checked checkbox in 13th column

function send_emails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var checkboxes_column = 13;

  var data = sh.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();

  data.forEach((row,i) => {
    if (row[checkboxes_column-1] == 'TRUE') {

      // you can use html tags in your message :)
      var msg = `<p>Hi,</p>
        <p><font size=5>I hope you're <font color='red'>well</font>.</font></p>
        <p>Best regards.</p>`;

      var addr = row[2];
      var copy = row[3];
      var subj = row[0] + " - Invoice Reminder - " + row[4];

      MailApp.sendEmail(addr, subj, msg, { 'htmlBody': msg, 'cc': copy });
      
      sh.getRange(i+1,checkboxes_column).uncheck();
    }
  });
}
```

First function sets checkboxes in 13th columns for the rows that have >60 in 6th column.

Second function sends emails for the checked rows. And you can uncheck any checkbox if you don't want to send email for some rows. And vice versa you can check any other row if you want to send the email even if the row doesn't meet the condition.

You can make the buttons to run the functions:

[image]

Comment: Would these need to go as separate scripts?

Comment: You can combine them into one function: `function main() { set_checkboxes(); send_emails() }` if you want. I don't know your workflow. You have not provided the description. So, it was just a guess.

Comment: thanks for this, i think i'll try one of the simpler ones for now, but i'm going to use this to learn, i dont want to implement something i wouldnt be able to edit or fix by myself down the line